# Cakephp 2 model beforeSave() not being called

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I can't figure out why this code isn't working. The `beforeSave` is not being called. It's supposed to fail the save and put some lines in the debug log, but it actually does save OK and no lines are written in the debug log.

```
<?php
class Link extends AppModel {
    var $name = "Link";
    var $belongsTo = array('Category' => array('className' => 'Category', 'foreignKey' => 'category_id'));

  public function beforeSave(){
        if ($this->data[$this->alias]['id'] == null) {
            $this->log("new record", 'debug');
            $link = $this->find('first',array('conditions' => array('Link.status = 1 AND Link.category_id = '.$this->data[$this->alias]['category_id']), 'order' => array('Link.order DESC') ));
            if (is_null($link)) {
                $this->data[$this->alias]['order'] = 1;
            }else{
                $this->data[$this->alias]['order'] = $link['Link']['order'] + 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->log("old record", 'debug');
        }
        return false;
    }
}   
?>
```

I am launching a save in the controller like this:

```
public function add($category_id = null)
    {
        if ($category_id == null) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Category id cant be null'),'default', array('class' => 'error-message'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'categories'));
        }
        else
        {
            if($this->request->is('post'))
            {
                $this->Link->create();
                $this->Link->set('category_id' => $category_id));
                if($this->Link->save($this->request->data))
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The link has been saved'),'default', array('class' => 'success'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index/'.$category_id));
                }
                else
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The link could not be saved. Please, try again.'),'default', array('class' => 'error-message'));
            }
            $this->set('category_id',$category_id);
        }
    }
```

Another question in StackOverflow points out that the `beforeSave` method needs to be declared in the Model. I've also done the same thing with another model.

Comment: In your add method, add `debug(get_class($this->Link));` What does it output?

Comment: Thanks for comment. It displays: 'AppModel' and the line # in the controller.

Comment: And there lies your issue. It's not finding your Link modeling so its creating one based off of AppModel. Where did you place that file and what is the name of the file for your Link model

Comment: Excelent thanks, file extension was the problem. If you want to keep record with answer go ahead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some general advice and some comments on your code for an answer:

1) If a model callback or any model method isn't working, make sure the correct model is being used and not the default model (AppModel). Check filename, class name, extension (in your case), and location.

2) You're using conditions array incorrectly (in this case).

`array('conditions' => array('Link.status = 1 AND Link.category_id = '.$this->data[$this->alias]['category_id'])`

You should really be doing:

```
array('conditions' => array('Link.status' => 1, 'Link.category_id' => $this->data[$this->alias]['category_id'])
```

3) Your redirect is being used wrong

`$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index/'.$category_id));`

Should be:

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', $category_id));
```

Comment: Excelent, still need to practice cakephp a lot!

Comment: it is also worth mentioning that you should always call the parent method as well: public function beforeSave() {parent::beforeSave(); ...} to ensure that the code of the parent classes is also executed properly.

Answer (score 2):

As written, your save() will always fail with this beforeSave().  beforeSave() must return true in order for the save function to succeed.
In fact, yours appears to always return false, guaranteeing a failed save.

From the Cake manual:

> Be sure that beforeSave() returns true, or your save is going to fail.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is not even being called, the false is just to test it before i do the actual saving, but thanks for the clarification